# Infinite Intersection/Union of regular languages

Tags: regular-languages, automata

Hello I'm having trouble understanding how an intersection/union of regular languages can be regular and in other case non-regular.

Can someone please give me some good examples?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/104269/83243 gives an infinite union of regular languages that is not regular.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/110082/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139464/755

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93464/755

Answer (score 9):

For every word $w$, there's a language $\{ w\}$, which is regular, and $\Sigma^* \setminus \{ w\}$, which is also regular.

But, we can express every language (regular or not) $L$ as an infinite union: $L = \bigcup_{w \in L} \{ w \}$, which is an infinite union of regular languages.

For intersection, you do the opposite:

$L = \bigcap_{w \not \in L} (\Sigma^* \setminus \{w \})$.

So, we know that there are regular languages, and non-regular languages, and they can all be expressed as infinite unions or intersections of regular languages.

Comment: OK and how about an infinite union/intersection of regular languages that is non-regular?
that is what troubles me more.

Comment: @Yogzis. You misunderstand my answer. You can use the construction above to construct *any* language: regular, non-regular, undecidable, etc. You pick your $L$, and we can define it as an infinite union or intersection of regular languages.

Answer (score 0):

Every regular language can be described as a DFA. So assume you have a DFA that represents language one, and a DFA that represents language two. Now construct a third DFA that represents the union of the first two DFA. Construct another DFA that represents the intersection of the first two DFA.

Comment: Since the resulting DFAs exist, then so does the the regular languages that correspond to this

Comment: This seems to half-answer half the question (why a finite union of regular languages is regular) but doesn't address the infinite part.