# Is the union of infinitely many regular languages always regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> Prove or disprove or this statement:

> The union of an infinite number of regular languages is regular.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you represent a non-regular language as an infinite union of finite languages?

Comment: Think about $L_k = \{a^kb^k\}$ (the language with exactly one word $a^kb^k$).

Comment: @ttnick I think no. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

*Every* language is a union of infinitely many regular languages:
$$
L = \bigcup_{w \in L} \{w\}.
$$