# Why are Regular sets not closed under infinite unions and intersections?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, type-theory

Why are Regular sets not closed under infinite unions and intersections, with my flawled reasoning I came to a conclusion that since infinite unions can have no relationship between strings of a language hence it must be regular but the opposite is infact true, can you please help me understand why so, and under what conditions is generally a language considered regular then (apart from the obvious reasons, a Finite automata can be drawn, regex can be written, a set has to be finite)?

Comment: The short answer is: because single strings are regular, and *every* language is an infinite union of single string. This is explained here: [Infinite Intersection/Union of regular languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67316/infinite-intersection-union-of-regular-languages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at $$\ell=\{a^p\mid p\text{ is prime}\}.$$

This language obtain from infinite union of
$$\bigcup_{i\geq 2, i\text{ is prime}}^{\infty}L_i$$
Where each $L_i=\{a^i\mid i\text{ is prime}\}$ that have one word.

Another example is $\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
That isn't regular and we can describe it by infinite union of regular languages
$$\bigcup_{i\geq 1}^{\infty}a^ib^i=a^1b^1\cup\dots.$$ Each $a^ib^i$ is language that have one word.

For intersection, i recommend you read the following [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67316/infinite-intersection-union-of-regular-languages).

Answer (score 4):

You state: *infinite unions can have no relationship between strings of a language*. Can you explain what you mean by this?

Meanwhile, *every* language is the infinite union of the singleton languages that each contain one element of the language.  Clearly, not every language is regular.

Comment: Likewise, every language is the infinite intersection of cofinite languages (complements of singleton languages), so by the same logic every language is an infinite intersection of regular languages.